# Phonegap offline application which dynamically creates pages

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova, offline

I'm starting to look in to phone gap. Basically I am using the local storage to add a load of records.
When the application is offline, I want it to go through the database and using jquery mobile create a page for each record. I want the application to be cross platform.

Because there is no server when offline, what language can I use to create dynamic pages? or do I have to start using something like appcelerator?

Comment: didnt get your question...  u can use jqm to get the data from db and then populate your page..

Comment: hi usually you need a server script like php/asp because i want to create a whole page as in I have no initial structure so I have to create all the div pages etc.. usually generated by the server. I think JSRender will do it. but thanks for you comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can all be done with client side templating using [jsRender](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/index.html)

Here is on of my [blog post with examples](http://roughlybrilliant.com/jsrender_json_apis_and_jquery_mobile) pulling json data from a flickr api and rendering pages in browser.  Probably a good start.  The syntax has changed a little since the post was first written so check the jsRender documentation to be sure of the exact syntax as the project progresses.